# Is there any method in Rails to convert minutes as integer to days, months, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of values in minutes that I would like to easily convert to its nearest matching like the following

```
10 => 10 minutes
1440 => 1 day
86400 => 2 months
525600 => 1 year
```

Is there any simple way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words). It operates directly on two `Time` objects, calculating the difference, but you could always do:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

def minutes_in_words(minutes)
  distance_of_time_in_words(Time.at(0), Time.at(minutes * 60))
end

minutes_in_words(10)
=> "10 minutes"
minutes_in_words(1440)
=> "1 day"
minutes_in_words(86400)
=> "2 months"
minutes_in_words(525600)
=> "about 1 year"
```

Comment: What would be the best way to gsub the `"about "` considering different locales? I just need the `"1 year"` not `"about 1 year"`.

Comment: Looks like you can just have the first argument without the second argument. Or, you can use `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now`.

Comment: `.match(/\d.*/)[0]` should strip off any leading words such as "about", "nearly" and "over"

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use `time_ago_in_words` and a little math to get the right date to operate on...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)       # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours)      # => about 15 hours
time_ago_in_words(Time.now)                 # => less than a minute
```

It's not (intentionally) precise, but it's already there.  Otherwise it's pretty easy to whip up your own using some division/modulo math...

Answer (score 2):

Don't think RoR has that, but that's easy

```
def to_days(minutes)
  minutes / (60*24)
end

def to_months(minutes)
  minutes / (60*24*30)
end

def to_years(minutes)
  minutes / (60*24*365)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below, I think it has what you need. Have a look at the function distance_of_time_in_words.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html