# How to output days as hours in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a constant like this:

```
TIME = 3.days
```

Is there a way to output this value in hours?

```
# => 72
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about `TIME/3600` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby or Rails has no direct method for this but if you google you can find a lot of way to do this.you can try followings:

> 3.days/1.hour

also take a look at [Is there any method in Rails to convert minutes as integer to days, months, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981206/is-there-any-method-in-rails-to-convert-minutes-as-integer-to-days-months-etc)

Answer (score 2):

`> 3.days / 3600
=> 72`

Not very intuitive, I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIME = 3.days
=> 259200
TIME/3600
=> 72
```

We have to covert it in hours (60 * 60 = 3600) :P

Answer (score 0):

### in_hours (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces new [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) conversion methods like [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as simple as:

```
3.days.in_hours
# => 72.0
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38699).